# Actual data reduction using Principal Component Analysis

Tags: pca

I have a general/basic question regarding PCA.

The idea is to remove redundancy in the data by focusing on only the most relevant aspects, but, unless I'm mistaken, this doesn't entail actually looking at fewer FEATURES, just a small number of superpositions of all of the features involved. So, for example, if you start out with 10 features, you have a covariance matrix with 100 values, only 55 of which are independent (due to symmetry). Once you're found the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix, if you keep, say the top two, you've then reduced the number of things you're looking at from 55 to 20. Am I correct about this? Also, is there any deeper way to know from the PCA output which features are less relevant and can be removed from the analysis?

Also, lets say that you need to keep eight eigenvectors to contain 98% of the variance. While you have a useful basis to describe your system, have you really gained anything in terms of simplicity and compactness of data?

I'm new to this, so thanks very much for any help/advice you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The idea is to remove redundancy in the data by focusing on only the most relevant aspects

Almost. PCA is just a representation of your data onto an orthogonal basis. This basis still has the same dimensionality as your original data. Nothing is lost...yet. The dimensionality reduction part is completely up to you. What PCA ensures is that the top k dimensions of your new projection are the best k dimensions that your data could possibly be represented as. Best is with respect to the variance explained.

> this doesn't entail actually looking at fewer FEATURES, just a small number of superpositions of all of the features involved.

Right - we don't reduce the number of features, just the number of dimensions. The new dimensions are linear combinations of the original features. In most cases, these new dimensions don't have much meaning with respect to the original features. i.e. the first principle component could be something like = 2.5 * column A - 0.5 * column B + 0.3 * column C. Who knows what that means...

> Once you're found the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix, if you keep, say the top two, you've then reduced the number of things you're looking at from 55 to 20. Am I correct about this?

I'm not sure what you mean by "looking at". I generally don't look at the covariance matrix. What if you had 50 variables? 100? That's a lot of entries to eyeball :) When performing reduction, we usually care about the variation explained by the top k eigenvectors. If k < p, then we are "looking at" k dimensions instead of p dimensions.

> Also, is there any deeper way to know from the PCA output which features are less relevant and can be removed from the analysis?

Sort of. In my experience, I could only extract meaningful data when the dimensionality wasn't too large. The idea is to look at the top few principle components and look at the weights of the features in them and see if they can reveal a story.

For example, say you perform PCA on a dataset that represents adult intelligence scores, and the variables measured are `information retrieval`, `pattern completion`, `arithmetic`, etc... And say your top 2 eigenvectors are the following:

```
PC1 = - 0.5 * info -  0.3 * pattern - 0.1 * arithmetic
PC2 = + 0.1 * info -  0.9 * pattern - 0.01 * arithmetic
```

Observations:

1) Since all components of `PC1` are roughly the same magnitude and same sign, this suggests a positive covariance among the three variables. This means that, to a one dimensional approximation, the differences between people are primarily differences in overall ability, as opposed to, say, differences in arithmetic only.

2) `PC2` is dominated by `pattern completion` suggesting that this task is somehow different in important ways than the other tasks in distinguishing between people's test scores.

3) `arithmetic` doesn't appear to play a significant role compared to the other test measures. Perhaps this feature could be removed?

> While you have a useful basis to describe your system, have you really gained anything in terms of simplicity and compactness of data?

That all depends on what value you get from having 8 dimensions instead of 10. If the top two or three are significant (say 60, 70% variance explained) then perhaps plotting them could yield some insight. Otherwise, PCA could also be used as a pre-processing step for further analysis.

Comment: Thank you very much ilanman for your thoughtful and helpful comments.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer if it suits you.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is a bit confused. If you have 10 original features, then PCA will produce 10 **new** features with all the correlation removed. You then select the top-k of those new features, where `k` is chosen so that a large amount of variance is retained.

> lets say that you need to keep eight eigenvectors to contain 98% of
>   the variance.

This situation happens when there is little correlation between the original features. PCA works by removing correlation, so if there is little correlation to start with, then you'll need a lot of new features (eight in your case) to retain a large amount of variance.

This [PCA tutorial](http://www.octoberraindrops.com/publications/Phan_2016_IntroductionToPCA.pdf) is a really easy-to-read introduction on the topic. It will probably answer all your questions. There are also a lot of statistics or machine learning textbooks on the subject.